# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext Dependencies issue

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, ghostscript

I am installing `ghostscript` on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I am getting error for make command due to dependencies :

> **/usr/bin/ld:** cannot find -lXext collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [bin/gs] Error 1

But I have libraries:

`locate libXext.so`

- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0`

Are these sufficient or I need some more libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run: `apt-get install libxext-dev`
It worked for me.

I tried to install Ghostscript 9.18 Source version

Answer (score 2):

You need to install ***libxext-dev*** package.

Run: `apt-get install libxext-dev`